# Mod_wsgi versus fapws3 - Django

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi, wsgi, fapws3

is there a difference between using **FAPWS3** and **MOD_WSGI** when dealing with **Django**?

FAPWS3 seems alot faster when serving requests toward Python scripts. I would like to know if I'm missing out anything. :)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

The underlying web server is not the bottleneck, it is your application and database access. The differences between any underlying web server are going to very minimal or non existent in the context of an actual full application stack. You cannot base decisions on hello world type tests as they are pretty meaningless. Decisions should therefore be based on the quality and stability of the hosting solutions under load, as well as ease of configuration and support, including your own competence to manage a particular setup. If you have no idea how to configure and support a particular web server properly, eg., Apache, then why would you use it.

Answer (score 2):

here is the best explanation what i ever seen in the web at the moment. 
http://nichol.as/benchmark-of-python-web-servers

Quote from nichol.as

> When you are just interested in quickly hosting your threaded
>   application you really can’t go wrong with Apache ModWSGI. Even though
>   Apache ModWSGI might put a little more strain on your memory
>   requirements there is a lot to go for in terms of functionality. For
>   example, protecting part of your website by using a LDAP server is as
>   easy as enabling a module. Standalone CherryPy also shows great
>   performance and functionality and is really a viable (fully Python)
>   alternative which can lower memory requirements.
>
> When you are a little more adventurous you can look at uWSGI and
>   FAPWS3, they are relatively new compared to CherryPy and ModWSGI but
>   they show a significant performance increase and do have lower memory
>   requirements.

Comment: Apache/mod_wsgi doesn't need to put more strain on your memory requirements if you configure it properly. Most people don't.

Comment: What configure properties do you mean?, its not so many things to play in mod_wsgi conf

Comment: Which Apache MPM you use. Whether you use mod_wsgi embedded or daemon mode. How many process/threads you use for both Apache MPM settings and mod_wsgi daemon mode if that is used. Whether keep alive used. Whether unnecessary Apache modules are stripped. There are a bunch of things one can do or tweak.